# Write a query with "like" statement

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I want to write a query that selects items that their titles are starting with an alphabet, something like:

```
select * from items where title like "A%";
```

But some of item names are starting with "A or 'A and I want to know if it's possible so my query contain all those forms of titles.

Comment: `title like 'A%' or title like '"A%' or title like '\'A%'`? mysql does support regexes for matching, which may be somewhat more efficient than checking 3 different likes against the same field.

Comment: @MarcB Can you show me how can I use those regexes for my probelm?

Comment: `... where title regexp('^?A$')`. docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from items where title like 'A%' or title like '\'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use regexp if there are to many possibilities to OR them.

Comment: Mysql has a REGEXP and RLIKE expressions that can do this.